# fallo en fetch js para enviar un dato usando boton (js)

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo el siguiente chat que estoy haciendo con fetch entre js y PHP
Inicio sesion , cuento con un array de usuarios

```
    <?php

    if(isset($_SESSION)){
        session_start();
    }
    
    
    
    $users = [
        1 => ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Test1', 'value'=> '1'],
        2 => ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Test2', 'value'=> '2'],
        3 => ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Test3', 'value'=> '3'],
    ];
    
    
        try{
        $user = $_GET['user'];
    }catch(exception $ex){}
    
    try{
        unset($users[$user]);
    }catch(exception $ex){}
    
    $filename = 'text'.$user.'.txt';
    if(!file_exists($filename)){
        $open = fopen($filename, 'w');
        fclose($open);
    }
    
    $_SESSION['id'] = $user;
    
    
    
    
    if(isset($_POST['read'])){
        $users = $_SESSION['id'];
        $filename = 'text'.$users.'.txt';
        set_time_limit(0);
        $result = ['users' => $users];
        $text = null;
        while(true){
            try{
                $text = file_get_contents($filename);
            }catch(exception $ex){}
            if(!empty($text)){
                $result['text'] = $text;
                file_put_contents($filename, '');
                break;
            }
            sleep(1);
        }
        header('content-type: application/json');
        die(json_encode($result));
    }
    
    if(isset($_POST['write'])){
        $users = $_SESSION['id'];
        $userTo = $_SESSION['id'];
        $filename = 'text'.$userTo.'.txt';
        

        $result = ['ok' => false, 'user' => $users];
        $message = $_POST['text'];
        try{
            file_put_contents($filename, $message);
            $result['ok'] = true;
        }catch(exception $ex){}
        header('content-type: application/json');
        die(json_encode($result));
    }
    
    //$user = 1;
    /*$users = [
        1 => ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Test1'],
        2 => ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Test2'],
        3 => ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Test3'],
    ];
    */
echo '<h1>'.$_SESSION['id'].'</h1>'
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Chat</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            outline: none;
        }
        #chat, #sendInputs {
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 360px;
            border: 4px solid green;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        #chat {
            min-height: 480px;
        }
        #input {
            width: 100%;
            height: 36px;
            line-height: 36px;
        }
        #send {
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0 auto;
            display: block;
            height: 36px;
            width: 64px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id=chat>
        
    </div>
    <div id=sendInputs>
        <select id=userTo>
            <?php
                foreach($users as $id => $obj){
                    echo '<option value="'.$obj['id'].'"               >';
                    echo $obj['name'];
                    echo '</option>';
                }
            ?>
        </select>
        <table style="width: 100%;">
            <tr>
                <td><input id=input type="text"></td>
                <td width=74><input id=send type="button" value="Enviar"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script>
        function read(){
            fetch('', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
                },
                body: 'read='
            }).then(r => r.text()).then(result => {
                console.log(result);
                try{
                    var json = JSON.parse(result);
                    if(typeof json.text !== 'undefined' && json.text != ''){
                        var div = document.createElement('div');
                            div.className = 'mssg';
                            div.innerText = json.text;
                            chat.appendChild(div);
                    }
                }catch(ex){}
                read();
            });
        };
        function write(){
            var text = null;
            var user = null;
            try{
                text = input.value.trim();
                user = userTo.value.trim();
                
            }catch(ex){}
            console.log('text:', text, user );
            if(text !=  null && text != ''){
                
                fetch('', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
                    },
                    body: 'write=&text='+text
                }).then(r => r.text()).then(result => {
                            
                    console.log(result);
        
                });
                input.value = '';
            } 
            else{
                input.focus();
            }
        };
        send.onclick = function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            write();
        };
        read();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Mi error que estoy tratando de solucionar es que quiero poder enviarle al usuario 2 su respectivo mensaje.
A la hora de hacer el fetch quiero hacer el envío del user al formulario para guardarlo en la variable  $userTo pero no veo por que me falla.

Los datos traídos se ven por consola.

Revise esta guía para hacerlo pero aun no encuentro como pasarlo
https://www.todojs.com/api-fetch-el-nuevo-estandar-que-permite-hacer-llamadas-http/

Answer (score 0):

en la funcion write no llamaba al usario

```
function write(){
            var text = null;
            var usert = null;
            try{
                text = input.value.trim();
                usert = userTo.value.trim();
                
            }catch(ex){}
            console.log('text:', text, usert );
            if(text !=  null && text != ''){
                
                fetch('', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
                    },
                    body: 'write=&text='+text+'&userto='+usert //aqui
                }).then(r => r.text()).then(result => {
                            
                    console.log('write:'+result);
        
                });
                input.value = '';
            } 
            else{
                input.focus();
            }
        };
```

y en mi php debia cambiar la variable sesion id por el dato post de ese usuario

```
if(isset($_POST['write'])){
        $users = $_SESSION['id'];
        $userTo = $_POST['userto'];  //aqui
        $filename = 'text'.$userTo.'.txt';
        

        $result = ['ok' => false, 'user' => $users];
        $message = $_POST['text'];
        try{
            file_put_contents($filename, $message);
            $result['ok'] = true;
        }catch(exception $ex){}
        header('content-type: application/json');
        die(json_encode($result));
    }
```